# Is $L^2(\mathbb R, \mathcal P(\mathbb R), \#)$ well defined?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Is $L^2(\mathbb R, \mathcal P(\mathbb R), \#)$ well defined ? $\#$ is the measure that counts the points. If so, is $L^2(\mathbb R, \mathcal A, \#)$ the same as $L^2(\mathbb R, \mathcal A, \lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue, and $\mathcal A$ the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, $L^{2}$ is defined for any measure. In this case $L^{2}$ consists precisely of all functions $f$ such that there is an at most countable set $(x_n)$ with $f(x)=0$ for $x \notin (x_n)$ and $\sum |f(x_n)|^{2} <\infty$. The answer to the second question is obviously no.

Comment: +1 It might be useful for the OP to note that the $L^2$ spaces of $\#$ and $\lambda$ are not only obviously different, as you said, but are obviously different for two separate reasons. (1) Elements of $L^2$ are equivalence classes of functions w.r.t. almost-everywhere equality. For $\#$, all the equivalence classes are singletons; for $\lambda$, none of them are singletons. (2) All the $L^2$ functions w.r.t. $\#$ are some (but not all) of the elements of the zero equivalence class of $L^2(\lambda)$.

Comment: This is an example of an unseparable Hilbert space.